# How does anaerobic burst-flight performance scale with mass?

Tags: bio-mechanics, flight, allometry

Quails employ anaerobic burst flight to escape predators and the *Quetzalcoatlus northropi* have most likely used it during launch and climb out, then transition to soaring.

Now, I have read these papers, from [Marden](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/James_Marden/publication/15014212_From_damselflies_to_pterosaurs_How_burst_and_sustainable_flight_performance_scale_with_size/links/0f31752dd3b74e95b2000000.pdf), [Witton](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2981443/) and  [C.J. Pennycuick](http://jeb.biologists.org/content/150/1/171)

I won't play pretend I really don't know that much about bird flight mechanics, so I easily got confused reading them.

**How does anaerobic flight performance scale with mass?**